# Probability of picking $3$ same digits out of $4$ randomly chosen digits.

Tags: probability, statistics

My thought is that we have $10$ digits, so $10$ different choices to pick the digit that will be the same. Then we have $4$ different positions to put the digit that is not the same with the other three digits and $9$ digits to do that with. 
That leaves us with $10 \cdot 4 \cdot 9=360$ different choices out of $10^4$.
So the probability must be $\frac{360}{10^4} = 0.036 = 3.6$%

I'm pretty sure that this is wrong but I don't know why. Any thoughts?

Update: Turns out my calculations were right.

Comment: If you want to exclude the case where all digits are the same, this is in fact the correct answer.

Comment: The answer you give of $\frac{360}{10^4}$ is the correct answer to the question of how many four-digit strings there are where exactly three of the digits match.  If you are asking a question along the lines of "I randomly choose four digits.  Among those I randomly choose three of them.  What is the probability they all match?"  then this is a totally different question.  For that, you should be able to see that this is the same as just picking three digits directly without having to go through the middle step and will be $\frac{1}{100}$

Comment: If it is indeed correct help me out a bit. Using the same method as above I calculated 5040 different choices where non of the digits are the same, 4320 where 2 digits are the same, 360 where 3 digits are the same and only 10 where all 4 digits are the same. Adding them up gives us 9730 which is 270 short of making 10^4 as it should.

Comment: If all digits are different this can be done in $10\times 9\times 8\times 7 = 5040$.  If there is exactly one pair of digits which are the same, for example `1123` this can be done in $10\times \binom{4}{2}\times 9\times 8 = 4320$.  *If there are two pairs of digits which are the same but different from eachother*, for example `1122` there are _____.  If there are three digits the same there are $360$ and if there are all four digits the same there are $10$ possibilities.  You just forgot a case.

Comment: Thank you very much JMoravitz.